# creating water mark using jquery and asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to create watermark using asp.net and jquery. I have a page with textboxes like this:

```
<tr>
        <td>
            <%=GetLocaleResourceString("Address.FirstName")%>:
        </td>
        <td>
            <nopCommerce:SimpleTextBox runat="server" ID="txtFirstName" Width="165px" class="watermark" Text="Type your First Name" 
    Tooltip="Type your First Name" ErrorMessage="<% $NopResources:Address.FirstNameIsRequired %>">
            </nopCommerce:SimpleTextBox>
            <asp:Label ID="lblShippingAddressId" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%=GetLocaleResourceString("Address.LastName")%>:
        </td>
        <td>
            <nopCommerce:SimpleTextBox runat="server" ID="txtLastName" Width="165px" ErrorMessage="<% $NopResources:Address.LastNameIsRequired %>">
            </nopCommerce:SimpleTextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

where nopCommerce:SimpleTextBox is a user control like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
    Inherits="NopSolutions.NopCommerce.Web.Modules.SimpleTextBox" Codebehind="SimpleTextBox.ascx.cs" %>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvValue" ControlToValidate="txtValue" Font-Name="verdana"
    Font-Size="9pt" runat="server" Display="Dynamic">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

I am following this article:

http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/archive/2011/11/24/creating-a-simple-watermark-effect-using-jquery.aspx

and adding css class and title in page where textbox control is used ( please see title and css in first markup).

but when i see page source I get this markup :

```
<input type="text" style="width:165px;" class="textBox" id="ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_ctrlCheckoutSinglePage_ctrlCheckoutBillingAddress_ctrlBillingAddress_txtEmail_txtValue" name="ctl00$ctl00$cph1$cph1$ctrlCheckoutSinglePage$ctrlCheckoutBillingAddress$ctrlBillingAddress$txtEmail$txtValue">
```

No CSS no title added. Please suggest me how to add watermark ?

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not applying `class="watermark"` for the `txtValue`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

It should be

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" class="watermark" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I applied it in page where this textbox control is being used but when page renders, class="textBox" is added.